# Tkinter Scroll Window Does Not Scroll

Tags: user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-entry, vertical-scrolling

Probably an easy question for a Tkinter veteran but why can't I scroll in my window?
If you run this code and add multiple data ports with the button, you will see what I mean.
Can anyone modify my code to make the scroll window work please?
I am not very well versed in Tkinter yet as I am with other similar tools in other languages so I'm sure there's going to be a lot to edit here.

```
from tkinter import *

fields = 'Buffer Depth \n(# of max-sized packets)', 'Payload Size \n(Max=1500bytes) ', 'Duplicate Quantity'
entries =[]

root = Tk()
root.title(string= 'Buffer Testing Tool')#create window title
root.geometry('500x750')#main window dimensions
root.configure(bg= 'crimson')

canvas = Canvas(root, height = 1000)
scroll_y = Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
frame = Frame()

options = ["Transmit", "Receive"]

def makeform(root, fields):#this will organize and align the labels of the entries plus the entry fields
    numberCheck =0
    
    for field in fields: 
        row = Frame(canvas)
        if (numberCheck==0):
            firstES = Label(row, text= "Data Port 1", anchor = 'center', fg = "blue")#first ES label  
            firstES.pack() 
            DPtype = Label(row, text = 'Type', width=19, anchor = 'nw')
            DPtype.pack(side= LEFT)
            clicked= StringVar()
            clicked.set(options[0])
            drop = OptionMenu(row, clicked, *options) 
            drop.pack(side = LEFT, padx=5, pady= 5)
            numberCheck=1
            row.pack(side=TOP, fill=X, padx=5, pady= 5)
            entries.append((field, clicked))
            rowNew= Frame(canvas)
            lab = Label(rowNew, width=20, text=field, anchor = 'w')
            lab.pack(side=LEFT)
            ent = Entry(rowNew)
            ent.pack(side=RIGHT, expand = YES, fill=X)
            rowNew.pack(side=TOP, fill=X, padx=5, pady= 5)
            entries.append((field, ent))
        else:
            lab = Label(row, width=20, text=field, anchor = 'w')
            ent = Entry(row)
            row.pack(side=TOP, fill=X, padx=5, pady= 5)
            lab.pack(side=LEFT)
            ent.pack(side=RIGHT, expand = YES, fill=X)
            entries.append((field, ent))
    #return entries
    
def addEntryField():
        next_row = int(len(entries)/4)+1
        numberCheck =0
        for field in fields:
            row = Frame(canvas)
            if (numberCheck==0):
                nextES = Label(row, text= ('Data Port ' +str(next_row)), anchor = 'center', fg = "blue")
                nextES.pack()
                DPtype = Label(row, text = 'Type', width=19, anchor = 'nw')
                DPtype.pack(side= LEFT)
                clicked= StringVar()
                clicked.set(options[0])
                drop = OptionMenu(row, clicked, *options) 
                drop.pack(side = LEFT, padx=5, pady= 5)
                numberCheck=1
                row.pack(side=TOP, fill=X, padx=5, pady= 5)
                entries.append((field, clicked))
                rowNew= Frame(canvas)
                lab = Label(rowNew, width=20, text=field, anchor = 'w')
                lab.pack(side=LEFT)
                ent = Entry(rowNew)
                ent.pack(side=RIGHT, expand = YES, fill=X)
                rowNew.pack(side=TOP, fill=X, padx=5, pady= 5)
                entries.append((field, ent))
            else:
                lab = Label(row, width=20, text=field, anchor = 'w')
                ent = Entry(row)
                row.pack(side=TOP, fill=X, padx=5, pady= 5)
                lab.pack(side=LEFT)
                ent.pack(side=RIGHT, expand = YES, fill=X)
                entries.append((field, ent))
        #return entries

if __name__=='__main__':
    b1 = Button(root, text = 'Generate XML File', command=root.quit, anchor = 'center')
    b1.pack(side= BOTTOM, padx=5, pady=5)
    b2 = Button(root, text = 'Run TTE-Build', command=root.quit, anchor = 'center')
    b2.pack(side= BOTTOM, padx=5, pady=5)
    b3 = Button(root, text = 'Run TTE-Plan', command=root.quit, anchor = 'center')
    b3.pack(side= BOTTOM, padx=5, pady=5)

    addEntryButton = Button(root, text= 'Add Data Port', fg = "Blue", command = addEntryField)
    addEntryButton.pack(side= BOTTOM, anchor = 'n', padx=5, pady= 5)
    
    ents = makeform(root, fields)#the creation of the window happens here
    root.bind('<Return>', (lambda event, e=ents: fetch(e)))#after hitting 'Enter' this will collect the entered data from the user
    
    canvas.create_window(0, 0, anchor= 'nw', window=frame)
    canvas.update_idletasks()

    canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"), yscrollcommand=scroll_y.set)

    canvas.pack(fill='both', expand=True, side='left')
    scroll_y.pack(fill='y', side='right')
    root.mainloop()

def fetch(entries):#this will print what what the entry fields are named plus what is written down in the entry fields (regardless of the # of fields)
    for entry in entries:
        field = entry[0]
        text = entry[1].get()#collect the entry for the fields
        print('%s: "%s"' % (field, text))

def Message1():
    XMLdone = Label(root, text= "XML File Generated!!")
    XMLdone.pack()

def Message2():
    XMLdone = Label(root, text= "TTE-Plan has been completed!!")
    XMLdone.pack()

def Message3():
    XMLdone = Label(root, text= "TTE-Build has been completed!!")
    XMLdone.pack()

#Note: The Payload Size must always be greater than or equal to 18 bytes less than the corresponding VL.
```

Comment: Please only ask one question at a time.

Comment: Sorry, I solved my other question.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with the code. The first is that the frame you're adding to the canvas isn't a child of the canvas, but it needs to be. You should also give this window a more descriptive name than just `frame`.

So, create the frame like this:

```
canvas = Canvas(root, height = 1000)
scroll_y = Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
inner_frame = Frame(canvas)
canvas.create_window(0, 0, anchor= 'nw', window=inner_frame)
```

The second problem is that you're not updating the `scrollregion` of the canvas with the inner frame changes. This is typically done by adding a binding to the `<Configure>` event of the inner frame:

```
inner_frame.bind("<Configure>", lambda event: canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")))
```

The third problem is that you're adding rows to the canvas rather than to the frame. You need to make your rows children of this inner frame.

```
    for field in fields:
        row = Frame(inner_frame)
        ...
            rowNew= Frame(inner_frame)
        ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution to this @BryanOakley ! It works exactly how I needed it to now. Much appreciated!!